# 100 € (einschließlich 10 €) – 100 € or 110 €?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Suppose a *Mahnung* holds the following phrase:

> EUR 100,00
>
> (einschl. EUR 10,00 Mahngeb.)

Does this mean the total is

- 110 EUR (`100 + 10`) or
- 100 EUR (`90 + 10`)?

[Duden.de states](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einschlieszlich_inklusive_samt_nebst) that *einschließlich* is a synonym of *inklusive*, which I'm sure means the total is 100 €, but is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: Just a side note. This would be considered too much for the 1. Mahnung.

Comment: @Piglet no worries, just an example, not based on real numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your guess was right, `einschl.`/`einschließlich` is [translated](http://www.dict.cc/?s=einschl) as `inclusively`, so the amount is 100€ = 90€ + 10€.

If the amount would be 110€ = 100€ + 10€, you would use `zuzüglich` (abbreviated `zzgl.`)

Answer (score 17):

Without a doubt that means "100 Euro (including 10 Euro fees)", i.e. the amount asked for is 100=90+10.

(I am a native German speaker and a businessman.)

Comment: On a side note: *einschl.* is very uncommon when talking about prices and fees. *inkl.* for *inklusive* is the usual term. The opposite would be *zzgl.* for *zuzüglich*.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff: Ich finde nicht, dass »einschließlich« oder die Abkürzung »einschl.« unüblich sind. Möglicherweise gibt es da regionale Unterschiede. Zumindest in Österreich ist »einschließlich« durchaus gängig.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Sicher? *Inklusive* erwarte ich eher bei Preisen und Angeboten. In Mahnungen und Rechnungen ist *einschließlich* häufiger. Auch Steuerangaben - einschließlich Mehrwertsteuer statt inklusive MWSt. Das Gegenteil ist in der Tat *zuzüglich*.

Comment: @Chieron Das kann natürlich sein. Mahnungen erhalte ich so selten. :-) Bei Rechnungen sehe ich eigentlich *inkl.* oder *zzgl.* häufiger, aber das kann auch täuschen. Andere Formulierung wäre hier auch: „Enthaltene Umsatzsteuer: X EUR“

Comment: @Janek & Chieron: Hier treten bestimmt regionale Unterschiede zu Tage, insbesondere zwischen Österreich und Deutschland, vermutlich auch zur Schweiz. Gerade in Österreich habe ich lange "inkludiert" gehört, was sich - meiner Auffassung nach - erst in den letzten Jahren auch in Deutschland verbreitet.

Comment: @Thomas die österreichische Grenze ist weit entfernt.. (Norddeutschland)

Answer (score 2):

*Einschließlich* means including. Including literally means "it is **already** included".

The opposite would be *ausschließlich*, which means excluding. Excluding literally means "it is **not already** included" (hence excluding).

A reason for using *einschließlich* could be to provide some detail concerning what is accumulated in the number. A reason for using ausschließlich could be to make you aware that additional payment is required.